# cannot download Safari 6.0.2 update from App Store on ML

Tags: macos, safari, mac-appstore, software-update

As by the title!  I have an update notification:

```
Safari 6.0.2
 Safari 6.0.2  is recommended for all users running Mountain Lion 
 v10.8.2 and includes security updates.  For more information, please
 visit: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1222
```

I try to update and I get:

```
 An error has occurred
 The operation couldn’t be completed. 
 (NSURLErrorDomain error -3001.)(102)
```

Is this a problem my side?  If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: The temporary download issues are resolved - this was of use and we can keep it around so people know sometimes the updates do not roll out smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a direct Apple link: http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/53/02/041-8081/2jwp4wjrwygtm4lc608qy4h0n4a9yyq37g/Safari6.0.2Mountain.pkg

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4338186?start=45&tstart=0 the problem is on the Apple side of things and thus there is nothing to do aside from waiting.  If one does not want to wait the iPhoto update is available from here: http://support.apple.com/downloads/ while the safari update seems to be available from CNet http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=Safari+6.0.2&platformSelect=Mac&tag=srch&searchtype=downloads&filterName=platform%3DMac&filter=platform%3DMac though I will not be downloading a *security update* from a third party!

Answer (score 0):

As I have the same problem here, It's likely to be DNS issue with apple's CDN servers. So my take is that this is a temporary internet issue and nothing you can do but wait for it to clear up.